# ASP.Net MVC Moq SetupGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, moq

I am starting out with TDD using Moq to Mock an interface that I have:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    void Commit();
    TopListService TopLists { get; }
}
```

From the samples I have seen I would expect SetupGet (or Setup) to appear in the intellisense when I type

```
        var mockDataService = new Mock<IDataService>();

        mockDataService.
```

But it is missing. Could someone suggest why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/detail?name=Moq.4.0.10827.zip).

Comment: changed from Moq 2.0 to 4.0 and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with your project setup, rather than with Moq.

- Check that your source code compiles successfully (or `Mock<IDataService>` will be meaningless).
- Check that your test project is referencing Moq.
- Check that the `Mock` you're using is `Moq.Mock` and not from another namespace.
- Otherwise I'd put money on it being Visual Studio. Close it down, open it up again, see if Intellisense wakes up.

If you can type the code that ought to work and make it build, then it's definitely Visual Studio playing up.